# How to ensure 'loops' in a matrix are zero net gain?

Tags: matrices, optimization, puzzle

I'm not sure how exactly to pose this question. Anyway, I have a 2D 16x16 square matrix that defines the cost of transitions from one state to another for a system. So for instance, the entry in the (0, 15) position defines how costly the transition from state 15 to state 0 is. I know the cost of transitions for all corners. That is, (15, 0), (0, 15), (0, 0), and (15, 15) are all known. I also know the cost of transitions for all entries in the final column i.e. for all transitions from state 15. Is there a way to figure out what the costs of the remaining transitions should be so that round-trips are 'balanced'? For instance, if I take state 0 -> state 5 -> state 6 -> state 4 -> state 0, the net cost should be zero. Of course, this means that costs can be negative! Further, entries on the main diagonal are all zero (i.e. no cost is incurred for 'same-state' transitions)

For a simplified example: In the matrix below, the dashes are entries that I need to fill in.

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & - & - & P\\
- & 0 & - & G_2 \\
- & - & 0 & G_1 \\
-P & - & - & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Edit: To further simplify the problem, one can assume that all middle transitions incur no cost. As in, we have:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & - & - & P\\
- & 0 & 0 & G_2 \\
- & 0 & 0 & G_1 \\
-P & - & - & 0
\end{bmatrix}

But I think the solution is trivial here, giving

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & P-G_2 & P-G_1 & P\\
-(P-G_2) & 0 & 0 & G_2 \\
-(P-G_1) & 0 & 0 & G_1 \\
-P & -G_2 & -G_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: If the matrix is seen as the adjacency matrix of a graph, you can reduce this problem to a flow problem; it should be way easier to picture the problem from a graph-theoretical pov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem itself is pretty trivial, and you don't need the additional assumptions you took in the simplification.  In fact, your assumptions might violate your condition of balance.

Because costs of a trip are are determined solely by the start and end of the trip:

1. Taking the trip $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow A$ has a zero cost, so the cost of $A\rightarrow B$ is $-1$ times the cost of $B\rightarrow A$, for any two states $A$.
2. Because the costs from state $15$ to each of the other states is known, the cost $A\rightarrow B=A\rightarrow15\rightarrow B=(15\rightarrow B)-(15\rightarrow A)$